# Contentful CLI trying to export content

Tags: contentful

I am trying to export some content from Contenftul following the steps laid out here
https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/

I run the command

```
contentful space export --config exportFrom.json
```

my exportFrom.json is structured as

```
{
  "spaceId": "A Space ID Contentful applies to Space I want to export from",
  "environmentId": "test",
  "managementToken":"A management token contentful gave me",
  "deliveryToken": "a token contenful says can be used for getting published content",
  "saveFile": true,
  "contentFile": "exportFrom.json",
  "skipContentModel": true,
  "skipEditorInterfaces": true,
  "skipContent": false,
  "skipRoles": true,
  "skipWebhooks": true,
  "contentOnly": true,
  "queryAssets": ["fields.title=null"],
  "downloadAssets": false,
  "host": "api.contentful.com",
  "errorLogFile": "myerrors.log",
  "maxAllowedLimit": 1000,
  "useVerboseRenderer": false
}
```

when I run with this I get the error message

```
YError: Invalid JSON config file: exportFrom.json
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: try removing below parameter from the config file.

"contentFile": "exportFrom.json",

Answer (score 1):

Well this was ridiculous, I had considered this might be the error but decided it wasn't likely - the example code in the contentful documentation is

```
contentful space export --config example-config.json
```

but guess what, the config option is going to need `./example-config.json` at least on Mac, but probably elsewhere as well.

on edit: note of course that my json file is `exportFrom.json` but the same principle holds.

Comment: there was another issue that I got after fixing the path - which was that current contentful cli doesn't know skipEditorInterfaces

Comment: oops I also forgot to change the name of the saved file so I overwrote my own config - silly